# Guardar ficheiro excel em uma matriz

Tags: java, microsoft-excel, matriz, vector

No exmplo apresentado abaixo tenho uma classe em java que vai buscar os dados de determinado ficheiro excel. Toda esta parte de ir buscar o ficheiro o programa faz, mas precisava agora que esses dados fossem guardados em uma matriz. Não sei de que forma fazê-lo.

```
public class UniFederal {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    List<List<String>> vecSample = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    double[] vect;
    int [][]matriz = new int[30][30];
    String[][] referencia = new String[][];

    File excel = new File("gestaoAlunos.xlsx");
    FileInputStream fich = new FileInputStream(excel);

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fich);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    Iterator<Row> rowIt = sheet.iterator();
    while(rowIt.hasNext()){
        Row row  = rowIt.next();

        int i=0, j=0;
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();          
        while(cellIterator.hasNext()){
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            System.out.print(cell.toString() + ";");
            //System.out.print(vecSample.get(i));
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    workbook.close();
    fich.close();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Uma matriz 2d nada mais é do que o cruzamento de linha com coluna. No caso do Excel, isso é facilmente visualizável no nome que as células recebem: A1, B2, D5 etc. O que queremos então é, em cada coluna, varrer todas as linhas, e só passar para a próxima coluna quando não houver mais linhas.

Vamos ao trecho do código que traduz isso:

```
Iterator<Row> rowIt = sheet.iterator();
int linha, coluna = 0; //nomes expressivos facilitam o entendimento
while(rowIt.hasNext()){ //entra na coluna
     Row row  = rowIt.next();
     Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();          
     while(cellIterator.hasNext()){ //começa a ver as linhas da coluna atual
        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
        referencia[coluna][linha] = cell.toString();
        linha++; //acabou a linha atual, vamos pegar a próxima
     }

     coluna++ //acabamos a coluna, vamos varrer a próxima
}
```